# Selecting all not returning any value

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with this and i dont know what i'm doing wrong, i need to show all when i select the value "a", and option not working with multiple values. I would appreciate that.

```
<body>
  <select id="options" multiple>
    <option value="a">Seleccione un año</option>
    <option value="a y2014">2014</option>
    <option value="a y2013">2013</option>
    <option value="a y2012">2012</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr class="a y2014"><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2014"><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2014"><td>2014</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2013"><td>2013</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2013"><td>2013</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2013"><td>2013</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2012"><td>2012</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2012"><td>2012</td></tr>
    <tr class="a y2012"><td>2012</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("options"),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

    select.addEventListener("change", function()
    {
        forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("tr"), function(tr)
        {
            tr.style.display = tr.className == select.value ? "" : "none";
        });
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: I think your problem might be that className will return all the classes (e.g. `a y2012`), whereas you just want to see if it *includes* `select.value`

Comment: Well, have a look what `select.value` is when you have selected multiple values…

Comment: Wait, never mind. I didn't see that you had the exact same for the `option` tags. It seems to work fine in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44Qyc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jacksondc pointed out, you want it to include select.value. So:

Change:

```
tr.style.display = tr.className == select.value ? "" : "none";
```

To:

```
tr.style.display = tr.className.indexOf(select.value)!=-1 ? "" : "none";
```